# Scheme: Why is there the need to use a cond here?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

I tried to write a (simple, i.e. without `eqan?`) `one?` function like such:

```
(define one?
  (lambda (n)
    ((= 1 n))))
```

But the above doesn't work though because when I call it like such:

```
(one? 1)
```

I get greeted with this error:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: #t (no arguments)
```

---

The correct way (from *The Little Schemer*) to write it is:

```
(define one?
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
      (else (= 1 n)))))
```

Why is there a need to use a `cond` with an `else` clause, instead of just returning `(= 1 n)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any reason why you would want to do that.  I'll check my copy of TLS when I get home to see if I can divine what's going on, but you're not missing anything fundamental about `cond` or anything.

Response to your note above:  It's not working because you have an extra set of parentheses in the body of the lambda.  It should be

```
(lambda (n) (= 1 n))
```

The extra parentheses in your version mean that instead of returning the value `#t` or `#f`, you're trying to call that value as a function with no arguments.

Comment: +1 yup, the problem was because I had the extra parenthesis; thanks for the explanation.

Comment: ...oh no, I just realized that if I had looked 5cm down the page before asking the question, I would have seen the `one?` function without the `cond` on the same page of the book; lesson learnt.

Comment: I saw that just now myself :)

Answer (score 0):

not having a copy of *The Little Schemer* handy, your example looks as if should work.  I think the `cond` is extraneous.  In psudeo-C the equivant (with cond) is:

```
int
one(int n)
{     
    switch (foo) {
        default:
           return  1 == n;
    }
}
```